# Session Handling Using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, session

Session Handling Using PHP Mysql ?

If I maintain session handling in database...

```
1) logged in 
2) save session id in database
3) when logged out session id deleted from db or flag changes
4) but I want to kill session when browser closed without logout
```

So How I can handle 4th condition . Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can use unset($sess_var). but the session should be automatically deleted whenever the browser closes.

Comment: Call the window event onUnLoad and kill the session on the call of ajax method.

Comment: I wonder is it really none of the questions from the "Related" section on the right side of this page did no help for you?

Comment: why did u store the session variable in database? u can use them whenever u want.

Comment: what all details do you insert into DB for a given `session_id`?

Comment: @DoSparKot : Yes session_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do logic using onunload browser event but this require very good logic because you can't be sure when user left your web page to remove the session from database:

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581179/on-browser-close-event), and the only way to do this is using javascript and ajax call to your web site and then using php script execute query where u gonna remove the session id,